# Is there any way to "precompile" Markdown in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, precompile, redcarpet

I have a rails app which displays static markdown from an sqlite database. Is there any way to "precompile" the markdown files like for css/js so that markdown does not need to be re-rendered for each request? If so, how do I do it?

There was a question [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255448) but I don't know how to cache markdown either. Some websites suggest that rendering markdown adds very little overhead to the app. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just cache the rendered output. Use something like this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/387-cache-digests

Comment: Thanks, I followed that and found out about page caching. Good to know :)